# Caching with Guava

Tags: java, caching, guava

What Guava classes are suitable for thread-safe caching? I use a composed key, which gets constructed on the fly, so softKeys() makes no sense, right? I saw somewhere ConcurentLinkedHashMap, is it the way to go? Is it already in the recent release? Sorry for the chaotic way of asking...

#### Update

This question is pretty old and looking through he answers could possible be a waste of time. Since long there's a [`CacheBuilder`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) which is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want `MapMaker.makeComputingMap`, but you mention `softKeys` so I assume you are already familiar with that class.

You are right about `softKeys` - it will not work if you compose keys on-the-fly, because `softKeys` causes the map to use `==` instead of `equals` for key comparison.  But you should be fine with `softValues` and `expiration`, as long as there is no side-effect from recreating an evicted entry.

Comment: This would be a possibility, except for the expiration. My

Comment: There are no side-effects from recreating, the values actually never expires. I haven't thought about softValues, this is a good idea. It actually protects against eating up all memory (sort of, SoftReference cleaning is a buggy in current Java).

PS: Sorry for the previous incomplete comment, I was too slow.

Comment: In Guava release 8, coming this week!, note that expiration() has been split into two forms: expireAfterWrite() and expireAfterAccess().  And there is also a maximumSize() option.

Comment: I knew about split expiration, but I didn't know about maximumSize(). That's what I need, I think. Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin coming this week! yay for that!

Comment: Well, it took until today -- sorry!

Answer (score 20):

The new Guava library with version 10.0 introduces the [`Cache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) interface which is designed especially for caching.

It comes with [`CacheBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), which is similar to [`MapMaker`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) and all caching methods of `MapMaker` will be removed in the release 11.

Example from the documentation:

```
Cache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .concurrencyLevel(4)
   .weakKeys()
   .maximumSize(10000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

`MapMaker.maximumSize()` is the long-term replacement for `ConcurrentLinkedHashMap`. CLHM remains the test-bed for improved algorithms for later porting if there is community consensus. I expect v2.0 will be the last release after porting those improvements to `MapMaker`, though. The project will remain alive as needed since it has a good user base (e.g. Apache Cassandra). I'm quite happy that Guava subsumed it.

Comment: MapMaker.maximumSize() is deprecated and scheduled for deletion in version 11

Comment: Yes, we replaced it with CacheBuilder which is a fork of MapMaker for accommodating a more cache focused design and api.