# Implement a monitor thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, monitor

Well I am not familiar with threads in java, so I am dealing with this problem: I have a singleton object who contains some objects (let say sessions) and each object has a duration time, so that means that after a some time one object is considered expired so it needs to be removed from (a pool - List in singleton) singleton. To do this I decided to have a thread that checks every 5 minutes (or 10 minutes or whatever) and clean up all session in the singleton class. How can I implement such a functionality avoiding any possible deadlock and or time consuming blocks. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Runnable cleaner = new Runnable() {
public void run() { /* remove expired objects here */ 
     //Using get method check whether object is expired 
   }
};
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
       .scheduleWithFixedDelay(cleaner, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: That's probably what I need. I didn't know about this class (Executor and all its derived classes) thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't implement it like that. Instead, I would delete the timed out sessions when a session is asked to the pool (not necessary at each get, though). This is, BTW, what is done by [Guava's CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), which you could use, since it's simple, tested, and provide useful features.

If you really want to go this way, then you should probably use a ConcurrentMap or ConcurrentList, and use a [single-thread ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29), which would wake iterate through the list and remove older sessions every X minutes.

Comment: Well this was my thought at the very beginning but the problem is this: what if we have for example 1 million sessions opened and 1000 of them are disconnected without calling a remove session method. So this would keep sessions in memory.

Comment: When *getting* a session from the list, the cache can iterate through the sessions and remove obsolete ones. Getting a session from the cache should be very frequent, else the cache wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: Create your session object with weak references so that they get garbage collected first.

Answer (score 2):

Is it an option for you to use a pre-existing in-memory caching-solution instead of writing your own?
If yes you could check out Google Guava, which offers a Caching-Solution among many other things.

1. See: [Caching with Guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734018/caching-with-guava)
2. See: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Comment: It could be, but I need a simple solution for the moment without having to learn a new API.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @quaylar (+1), use an existing caching technology, if you can.

If you can't, however, one solution is to use a java.util.Timer. Initialise it with the time till first session object expiry and put it to sleep. Then, on it awakening, have it remove your session object and reset it with the time to the next expiry time. Let java handle the timing aspects.

Comment: Well The problem is that session time is renewed each time there is the session called and it stays unchanged if this session is inactive for a period of time (e predefined time). So I don't know is the Timer renewable (resetting its time)? And does this mean we should have a Timer for each session? If so there so much memory consumption.

Comment: @elvis Hi, only one timer for the whole cache is required. This approach always sets the timer to be the offset required until the next object to expire's expiry time. So, you don't set the timer to be 30s on each awakening, you always set it to be whatever the time is until the next expiry... Now, beyond that depends on your underlying cache data structure. If it's ordered (TreeMap or List) then you know that the next object in order is the next to expire. So, no need to iterate the list to find the item(s) that will expire next.

Comment: You can use any timer mechanism, it's the approach that's important, not the implementation, so long as the VM is looking aftre your timer (daemon).

Comment: Well having an ordered collection allows you to only check the tail or the head so it is more clear and quick. The problem is: inserting is slower, retrieving is slower and the structure is actually a map because I need to find quickly a session by its id without having to iterate over whole collection. Also there is another problem, each time a session is renewed it must be removed and reentered in the sorted collection because the collection would then be unsorted (or I am wrong?), if so then then this increases the complexity.

Comment: @Elvis: First off sorry but I wrote TreeMap when I meant LinkedHashMap. Back on track, `LinkedHashMap` is an ordered collection that allows retrieval by key/ id (implements Map interface like HashMap) but maintains the insertion order. Insertion will be slower but marginal, compared to iterating the list for items to remove. Regarding "each time a session is renewed it must be removed and reentered in the sorted collection because the collection", I'd have thought you'd be removing the session from the cache anyway when a session expires and re-add it if/ when it's renewed.

Comment: I meant `LinkedHashMap, not `TreeMap`.

Comment: Well I have LinkedHashMap and it works like that: any time a session is created it as added to this map, and it has an initial duration time. If this session is called then its time is renewed. Removing the session and entering it again in the map would be a good solution. The problem is: the server has to focus on serving users as quick as possible and not perfectly managing the memory each time. This is something like: each time you create, copy, delete or update a big file in a file system , the OS decide to perform a disk defragmentation!!!

Comment: Yes, that would be a pain. Unless you can manipulate the list (remove, re-insert) after the response is sent. Not sure that's a good idea but then it's a trade-off against doing a full iteration every 30secs(or whatever). Could be peanuts in comparison. Think a test harness and some Impls may be useful. Can you report back any findings by any chance!?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like this : I am assuming the class for your singleton object is called singleton so you have something like this (its not perfect code)

```
public class Singleton {
   List<Objects> singletonList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Objects>);



}

public class RemoveExpiredItemsThread implements Runnable {

    private Singleton singletonReference;
    private int sleepTime = 5*60*1000;
    // the constructor

    // then the run method which is something like this

    public void run() {
       while(done == false) {
         Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
         singletonReference.removeItem();
       }  
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I did but I can't say for sure if this is the right solution.